# QuickFix C++ and SSL: Issue connecting to LMAX using sTunnel

Tags: c++, ssl, quickfix, fix-protocol, stunnel

### Goal:

Using `sTunnel` with QuickFix C++: To login to the LMAX UAT over `SSL-internet` and send `FIX 4.2` messages over a TCP connection. Another similar SO question [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52617392/establishing-a-connection-to-dukascopy-using-stunnel), but doesn't appear to solve this particular issue.

**OS:** Ubuntu 19.10 | **sTunnel version:** 5.55 | **Engine:** quickfix-1.15.1 | **Venue:** LMAX [UAT-LD4]

### Problem:

Cannot login to the UAT. After starting `sTunnel` and then running the client application which first sends a `LOGON` message, no authentication is received. LMAX have said the client server public IP addr has been whitelisted.

***Configs found further below.** When trying to login:

```
20210130-12:40:45.207811000 : Created session
20210130-12:40:45.208201000 : Connecting to 127.0.0.1 on port 143 (Source :0)
20210130-12:40:45.208384000 : Initiated logon request
20210130-12:40:55.217130000 : Socket Error: Connection reset by peer
20210130-12:40:55.217148000 : Disconnecting
```

The outbound `LOGON` message (taken from log) seems to adhere to the LMAX FIX specifications (**please ignore** the incorrect checksum as credentials have been changed). This may suggest that the issue lies with the TCP connection. The outbound `LOGON` message:

```
8=FIX.4.2|9=104|35=A|34=1|49=SENDER_XYZ|52=20210130-12:40:45.208309000|56=TARGET_XYZ|95=12|96=PASSWORD_XYZ|98=0|108=15|10=094|
```

**Expected result:** To receive a `LOGON` authentication from LMAX.

**Results:**

After following [this tutorial on installing and using sTunnel on Ubuntu.](https://hamy.io/post/0012/how-to-install-and-configure-stunnel-on-ubuntu/#gsc.tab=0) , `sTunnel` is then started with `sudo systemctl start stunnel4.service` and the service status checked, giving:
[image]

Once `sTunnel` is started, after starting the client application packets can be seen in Wireshark going from the client server to the LMAX UAT, but it seems that **no packets are returned from LMAX UAT**.
[image]

### System Logs

Running `journalctl -xe` produces the following logs.

1. While sTunnel is running: https://pastebin.com/YE6xyNcM
2. While sTunnel is running, and client app has been **started and then stopped:** https://pastebin.com/Vv55A35L

### Configuration and Setup

SSL certificates were generated using the following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -key key.pem -out cert.pem -days 1095
cat key.pem cert.pem >> /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
```

***The sTunnel config:**

```
pid = /var/run/stunnel4/stunnel.pid

[LMAX-UAT]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:143
connect = fix-order.london-uat.lmax.com:443
sslVersion = TLSv1
verify = 2
CApath = /etc/ssl/certs/
cert = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
checkhost = fix-order.london-uat.lmax.com
```

***The QuickFix config:**

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
HeartBtInt=15
ReconnectInterval=2
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=log
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=N
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1
SenderCompID=SENDER_XYZ
SocketUseSSL=N
TimestampPrecision=9

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.2
TargetCompID=TARGET_XYZ
SocketConnectPort=143
```

### Summary Questions:

1. Given the above details, can anyone determine what is preventing FIX communication over `SSL-internet` to the UAT at LMAX?
2. Based on the Wireshark activity, could this be a `sTunnel` issue instead of the formatting of the initial `LOGON` message?

Comment: The message 'TIMEOUTconnect exceeded, No more addresses to connect' and the Wireshark screenshot look to me as if the connection is not accepted by LMAX. I assume it is a firewall issue, i.e. that they did not whitelist the connection.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophJohn , LMAX said last week that the IP address had been whitelisted, but I agree regarding the Wireshark screenshot. Even if it was the format of the FIX message, I would still see some TCP packets coming from the UAT. Not sure where to go with this now.

Comment: Are you able to telnet their address?

Comment: I've just tried to telnet their IP and it's not possible/ the connection timed out, so I think this must be a permission issue. I am running this from a VPS, and I believe the collocation provider doesn't have permission to enable clients to establish TCP connections over SSL-internet (cross-connections only). I think this has narrowed it down. Thank you for your help @ChristophJohn

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe you can add the final solution later on. This could then help other people as well.

Comment: Of course- I'm not entirely sure of the solution quite yet (although it has been narrowed down), but I'll be sure to update the question with an answer once this has been solved. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

It appeared that indeed the IP address (as helpfully noted by [@Christoph John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4962355/christoph-john)) had not been correctly whitelisted by the server-side.

However, the problem persisted. In the sTunnel configuration, I had to change `sslVersion = TLSv1.1` to `sslVersion = TLSv1.2`.

As well as this, it appears that the UAT would not accept `FIX 4.2` messages. After changing the protocol version to `FIX 4.4`, I could finally `LOGON` to the UAT.